# Cannot decode stack traces using Eazfuscator.NET

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, .net-4.0, obfuscation, eazfuscator

We use Eazfuscator.NET 3.3 to obfuscate our code. However, after adding this line to our AssemblyInfo.cs file for the dll we wish to encrypt, we are still unable to decode stack traces using the password defined as their help suggested:

```
[assembly: Obfuscation(Feature="encrypt symbol names with PASSWORD", Exclude=false)]
```

Has anyone had success with decoding stack traces using Eazfuscator.NET who could tell me what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Please double-check the correctness of a password. Ensure it is the same for encryption and decoding. Please also note that the case of letters does matter.

Comment: I can verify that I am using the correct password, which in this case should be PASSWORD. But how do I verify that the password is the same for both encryption and decoding? The help only says to add this line as an assembly attribute.

Comment: Please take a look at documentation chapter _Troubleshooting --> Troubleshooting Features --> Stack Trace Decoding_. There is a password field where you can enter the password. Please tick "Show characters" checkbox to ensure that the entered password is correct.

Comment: I have done this, but no dice. I still cannot decode the stack trace.

Comment: Specifically, the help says to put the attribute in a file called ObfuscationSettings.cs, but I merely placed it in my AssemblyInfo.cs file. I wouldn't imagine it makes a difference but could this be why it isn't working?

Comment: BasedAsFunk, there is no difference where you put the attribute. Unfortunately Eazfuscator 3.3 is not a supported version anymore. If you want to get the qualified help and service I recommend you to consider the newer paid version. It backed up by a guaranteed support and update plan. If you are interested then please contact us and we will give you a good quote. (Disclaimer: my name is Oleksiy Gapotchenko, I'm the official person behind Eazfuscator.NET)

Comment: I must have made a typo when typing in the assembly attribute, copying and pasting the line from the help and changing the password fixed the problem. Thanks for the support

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ahh, the problem was due to a typo. Originally the attribute read

```
[assembly: Obfuscation(Feature="encrypt symbol names with PASSWORD", Exclude=false)]
```

when it should have been

```
[assembly: Obfuscation(Feature="encrypt symbol names with password PASSWORD", Exclude=false)]
```